# Have different urls for desktop and mobile sites

Tags: magento-1.8, url, url-rewrite, mobile

In my project, I want to have different urls for Desktop site and mobile site.

For example:

```
 www.example.com      // For Desktop

 www.example.com/m    // For Mobile site
```

How to do this?

Both have access to same Database.

Comment: And what's the difference between the mobile site and the desktop site? Do you use different store views with different themes? Different websites in one Magento installation? WIthout additional information, this is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the site as [explained here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-mobilize-your-magento-site-for-iphone-android-mobile-commerce/) for mobile

And manage the url from redirect to mobile site like [this](http://blog.woorank.com/2014/06/how-to-redirect-mobile-users-on-your-website/)

Comment: It would be better if you provide summary/explanation here. (_The links you provided could get broken in future_)